# English equivalent for Fünftonraum

Tags: terminology

What is an accurate English translation for the German "Fünftonraum".  The context of its use is in fingering diagrams for the first five notes of a scale, **not** the pentatonic scale. The best I can come up with is "five tone interval".

Comment: German doesn't use spaces in spelling compound words - English does. However, this is a superficiality that makes no difference in how word formation works. "Fünftonraum" is a straightforward compound that Germans understand transparently by understanding the component nouns. You can form a corresponding compound in English, and the result isn't any less official or authoritative than in German.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The music publisher "Edition Peters" translates Czerny's "24 Übungsstücke im Fünftonraum" with "24 Five-Finger Exercises" ([link](http://www.editionpeters.com/product/24-five-finger-exercises-op-777/ep2844)).

On amazon, similar note books are sold as "Five Finger Piano" or "5-Finger Piano".

There is also a Wikipedia-entry about [Five-finger exercise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-finger_exercise).

So I guess, **five finger** (with or without hyphen) is the English term you are looking for, although this is also the common name for [several plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_finger)s.

Comment: Thanks. Good lead. What I have found is that I need to formulate the English interpretation for musical terminology based upon the context of its usage.  I appreciate the links, which helped me wrap my Spanish-American-English language brain around this particular usage. Sechstonraum unfortunately does not mean what I hoped it would.
@kilian-foth